# Can't build Unity and Run UWP to Xbox One VS2019. Problem with Build tools

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, visual-studio-2019, xbox-one

I'm trying to port my Unity 2019.1 created Steam and mobile game to Xbox One and UWP. I can create a VS project and build and deploy to console. Running "Build and Run" from Unity 2019.1 throws up this error:

> D:_Programming Stuff\Unity\output_Data\ionAXXIA_UWP\Il2CppOutputProject\Il2CppOutputProject.vcxproj : warning : The build tools for Visual Studio 2017 (v141) cannot be found. Install Visual Studio 2017 (v141) to build using the Visual Studio 2017 (v141) build tools.

Is it possible to Build and Run from Unity to Xbox console, and if so, what do I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: Try installing Visual Studio 2017 (v141)

Comment: You can also just install the v141 platform toolset with VS 2019. Run the Visual Studio installer, Modify, go to Individual Components and select "MSVC v141 C++ build tools for x64/x86" (``Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64``) and then install.

Comment: Reset your Xbox to factory settings, reformat your PC and reinstall Windows, then reinstall Visual Studio. Be prepared to so that daily. Welcome to development on Microsoft platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno why I was downvoted. Turns out it was a bug fixed in 2020.1.0a4, 2018.4.10f1, 2019.2.6f1, 2019.3.0b4. So 2019.2 and 2019.3 were fixed but 2019.1 wasn't. A project migration to 2019.2 fixed the issue and didn't cause any other problems with my project.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/uwp-building-project-for-visual-studio-2019-generates-solution-that-targets-build-tools-for-vs-2017-tool-set-v141?_ga=2.235968517.563689385.1582629936-2037394333.1563991472